# A set K in R^n is compact if and only if every continuous function from that set to the set of real numbers is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

I am having a problem proving the above. If K is compact we can easily conclude that f(K) is bounded. (Since every continuous function takes a compact set to a compact set), how do we prove the converse?

Comment: The contrapositive of the converse is that if $K$ is not compact, then there exists an unbounded function $K \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Travis I understand that but how do we prove the existence of such a function?

Comment: See J.J.'s compact answer below for a construction of such a function.

Answer (score 4):

If $K$ is not compact, it is either not bounded or not closed.

If it is not bounded, take as your function $f \colon K \to \mathbb{R}$  the function $f(x) = \|x\|$.

If it is not closed, there is a point $a \in \partial K \setminus K$. Take as your function $f(x) = \frac{1}{\|x - a\|}$. Consider what happens along a sequence $K \ni x_n \to a$.